# Protocol charset conflict, ESMTP vs. XML in an email body

Tags: xml, parsing, character-encoding, smtp, protocols

We have a process in which XML is transferred to us via ESMTP in an email body.  The character set of the email body is specified as **ISO-8859-1**, and no encoding is specified for the XML. According to the protocol, the default is **UTF-8**.

The problem is our XML parser is throwing an exception when it encounters the ® character because it thinks it's parsing **UTF-8**, and the ® character in **UTF-8** is 2 bytes, not 1 as in **ISO-8859-1**.

1. Should we assume that the body is **ISO-8859-1** and thus override the XML encoding (**UTF-8**)?
2. More subjectively, is the email being sent incorrectly, and would it be better for us to try to interpret as **UTF-8** on our side or ask whoever is sending it to correctly and consistently specify the encoding?

Here is a sample email body with XML:

```
Delivered-To: ...
Received: ...
Received: ...
Return-Path: ...
Received: ...
Received-SPF: ...
Authentication-Results: ...
Received: ...
Thread-Topic: ...
From: ...
To: ...
Subject: ...
Date: ...
Message-ID: ...
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: text/plain;
 charset="iso-8859-1"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit
X-Mailer: Microsoft CDO for Windows 2000
Content-Class: urn:content-classes:message
Importance: normal
Priority: normal
X-MimeOLE: Produced By Microsoft MimeOLE V6.00.3790.4325

<?xml version="1.0"?>
...
   <comments>Super Widget®</comments>
...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [XML specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/) says in appendix F, concerning encoding detection:

> Also, in many cases other sources of information are available in addition to the XML data stream ifself.

So yes, in lack of an `encoding="..."` in the XML stream itself, you should rely on the external source, which in this case is the `Content-Type` header.